# This comment has not yet been published to Facebook

Tags: facebook

I am using FB:Comments on my page using XFBML. When I post a comment, an error comes up with the message "This comment has not yet been published to Facebook"

This is the code that I am using apart from the fb:comments tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init(
{appId :'APP ID',status:true,cookie:true,xfbml:true});
};

(function(){var e=document.createElement('script');
e.async=true;
e.src=document.location.protocol+'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);}());
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What attributes do you have set on the fb:comments tag? I believe all that's doing is the facebook connect/login side of things. Have you got the correct OG tags in place? You could also add in code to subscribe to the add comment event and see what's going on:

```
<script>
FB.Event.subscribe('comments.add', function(resp) {
   for(var i in resp){
      if(resp.hasOwnProperty(i)){
      console.log(i + "   " + resp[i]);
      }
   }
});
</script>
```

you may also need the channel file as detailed here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Answer (score 2):

It looks this problem comes with ".info" domains.
Or it might be that this happens with top level domains with 4 or more letters, like .info, .name or .mobi, though I haven't investigated into all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. If I use the example page (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) the comment gets posted on my wall, whereas doing the same in the comment box of my app does not, unless I pint them to a Facebook URL.

This works:

```
   <fb:comments   href="http://www.facebook.com/any-url/" ></fb:comments>
```

This doesn't if I do it from my app, but it works if I do it from my site (which doesn't really help for the purpose I need it to)

```
<fb:comments   href="http://www.mysite.com/any-other-url/" ></fb:comments>
```